Preserving Hierarchy With FastAPI + Pydantic + OpenAPI Docs
I am finishing up an API in FastAPI and using the OpenAPI documentation with pydantic to generate docs. One thing I've noticed, is that the hierarchy of nested models is not preserved when one field is an array of models.  The example below is the approximate structure of my model.
Class MyModel(BaseModel):
   description: str
   success: bool
...

Class TopLevel(BaseModel):
    message: str
    matches: List[MyModel] = Field(
        List[MyModel],
        description="An array of matches found",
    )

However, in the docs for FastAPI, the matches field simply shows as array<object> and lists the subentries as "Item"
matches Collapse all array<object>

    Items Collapse all object
    
        description Expand all(string | null)
        success Expand all(object | null)
        

What am I missing here? The structure is preserved in other nested scenarios when the nested fields are signular objects of another pydantic model. Why is array<object> being generated instead of array<MyModel>.
I've tried using TypeVar, list, and changing the annotation of the sub model. No luck in preserving the structure/class name.

Any reason why you're giving List[MyModel] as the first argument to Field? Wouldn't that mean that the default value is the (actual) List-typing hint? I can see how that could confuse any inferred types.

Seems to be a Swagger UI issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/9593

The problem seems to be with:
matches: List[MyModel] = Field(
        List[MyModel],
        description="An array of matches found",
    )

The first param in the field should either a default value or … which shows it is required parameter.
You can amend these lines to:
matches: List[MyModel] = Field(
        …,
        description="An array of matches found",
    )


I think you are correct that ... is the more appropriate entry. Unfortunately that did not solve the typing issue in the documentation Swagger generated documentation :(

Hm, that's interesting. Can you share how do you want the schema be displayed in swagger? Because from what I can see, what you are getting is the default behaviour.

I think Helen's comment is probably the root cause of the issue, there is probably a bug introduced in the latest version of swagger.
Seems to be a Swagger UI issue: github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/9593
